# Python 2.7 Selenium, How to NOT wait for a page to load

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, load, element

How to **NOT** wait for the whole page to load? There is a page that loads really slowly (it takes at least 3.5 minute to FULLY load the webpage) and I don't want to wait so long.

Is it possible that after `driver.get("slowwebpage.com")` selenium won't wait for the webpage to load but instead wait for a element let's say: `driver.find_element_by_id("element")` to be clickable/visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the page load timeout and catch the exception.

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
try:
    driver.set_page_load_timeout(seconds)
except TimeoutException:
    pass
```